# Objective-C, set and get variables in class object which is stored in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, class, object

I am trying to write my own class storing data about libraries and then store each object in an NSArray.

My interface:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface LibraryInfo : NSObject
{

NSString* name;
NSString* address;
NSString* link;
NSString* coordinates;

}

- (NSString*) getName;
- (NSString*) getAddress;
- (NSString*) getLink;
- (NSString*) getCoordinates;

- (void) setName: (NSString*)input;
- (void) setAddress: (NSString*)input;
- (void) setLink: (NSString*)input;
- (void) setCoordinates: (NSString*)input;

@end
```

My implementation:

```
#import "LibraryInfo.h"

@implementation LibraryInfo

- (void) setName: (NSString*)input
{
name = input;
}

- (void) setAddress: (NSString*)input
{
address = input;
}

- (void) setLink: (NSString*)input
{
link = input;
}

- (void) setCoordinates: (NSString*)input
{
coordinates = input;
}

- (NSString*) getName {
return name;
}

- (NSString*) getAddress {
return address;
}

- (NSString*) getLink {
return link;
}

- (NSString*) getCoordinates {
return coordinates;
}

@end
```

I write and store each object in the NSArray, like so:

```
LibraryInfo *library = [[LibraryInfo alloc] init];
[library setName:( ( name != nil && name.length > 0 ) ? name : @"No Name" )];
[library setAddress:( ( address != nil && address.length > 0 ) ? address : @"No Address" )];
[library setLink:( ( link != nil && link.length > 0 ) ? link : @"No Link" )];
[library setCoordinates:( ( coordinate != nil && coordinate.length > 0 ) ? coordinate : @"No Coordinates" )];
    
[libraries addObject: library];
```

Where 'libraries' is an NSArray.

Then I try to read the values like so:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[ libraries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] getName ];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[ libraries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] getAddress ];
```

I think it may be something to do with the setting of the values, or maybe they are not properly stored or retained, but I get the following error and a marker by my 'setName' method
when the App 'crashes' and pauses:

```
self    LibraryInfo *const  0x068a1760
input   NSString *  0x068a3550
name    NSString *  0x00000000
```

How do I fix this? I'm using Xcode 4.3 so no releases/retains needed.

Comment: Well, Xcode 4.3 does not in-and-of-itself mean "no releases/retains needed". You have to have chosen to use ARC for the project/target. Did you?

Comment: Also, the `LibraryInfo` class is almost all boilerplate code which would go away if you used declared properties. And all of your properties should have copy semantics. If you use declared properties, that's one keyword in each property declaration. If you implement the accessors manually, you have to invoke `-copy` in each setter.

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare properties. IVars aren't going to store your data the way you're expecting

LibraryInfo.h

```
@interface LibraryInfo : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* address;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* link;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* coordinates;
```

LibraryInfo.m

```
@implementation LibraryInfo
@synthesize name;
@synthesize address;
@synthesize link;
@synthesize coordinates;
```

Then creating libraries would be simple

```
LibraryInfo *library = [[LibraryInfo alloc] init];
library.name = (name.length > 0 ? name : @"No Name");
library.address = (address.length > 0 ? address : @"No Address")
library.link = (link.length > 0 ? link : @"No Link")
library.coordinates = (coordinates.length > 0 ? coordinates : @"No Coordinates")
```

Then in your TableView cell.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [libraries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [libraries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].address;
```

Comment: The check on the properties' length, and accompanying default value, should ideally be in the setter method, not outside the class.

Comment: In a perfect world absolutely. But when answering questions like these I try to only fix the key problem, and fill in their code for the rest so they can understand whats going on. If you just change all their code and concepts they will likely get lost and not have an answer to their problem. Strong believer in one step at a time haha.